# Подсчитать количество элементов массива, ключи которых равны числам

Tags: php, массивы, count

Есть в php такая функция, как count, с ее помощью можно узнать количество элементов в массиве. Возможно ли подсчитать количество значений массива, ключи которого только цифры?

Есть к примеру такой массив:

```
Array ( 0 => 'val 0', 1 => 'val 1', 2 => 'val 2', 'key 3' => 'val 3' );
```

Если использовать функцию count, то вернется значение 4. Есть ли в php функция, которая бы дала ответ в данном случае 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отфильтровать по числовым ключам (*в примере, с помощью функции* [is_int](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.is-int.php)) и посчитать количество элементов:

```
<?php
echo count(array_filter($arr, 'is_int',  ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
```

На всякий случай, если у вас версия PHP < 5.6

```
<?php
echo count(array_filter(array_keys($arr), 'is_int'));
```

Comment: Шикарно, большое спасибо!